# Copy data from one workbook to the other workbook sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA excel. I am trying to copy the data on a worksheet from a workbook to the other worksheet on another workbook. The user choose the file they want to open through File Dialog. However, I keep get the error of Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range. Can someone please enlighten me. Thank you.

```
Sub selectfile()
Dim FileToOpen As String
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet2.Range("A:Y").ClearContents
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Excel File to Open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx(*.xlsx),")
Sheet1.Range("B30").Value = FileToOpen
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
Set sheet = wb2.Worksheets(1)
wb2.Activate
sheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("OQC_Check_Tools.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")

End Sub
```

Comment: does the error come at set wb2=workbooks.worksheets("Sheet1") line? or at workboos.open line?

Comment: Error is on this line: Set sheet = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: try the index of the sheet instead of name.....something like set sheet=wb2.worksheets(1)

Comment: It works now but i want to copy the data from the file i opened to the workbook. How do i do that ?

Comment: sheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("OQC_Check_Tools.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")    this line in your code might take care of that... I guess

Comment: But its not working and giving me the same error as before

Comment: try  to index the sheets("sheet2") as sheets(2)

Comment: Nope its not working

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range

Comment: are you copying to the same workbook where the macro is?

Comment: yes, im trying to copy to the same workbook as the macro is

Comment: try thisworkbook instead of Workbooks("OQC_Check_Tools.xlsm") also dont use activate or select its not efficient programming

Comment: Now it is copying to a new sheet by creating a new sheet... How can i copy it to a current sheet in the workbook ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub selectfile()
Dim FileToOpen As String
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet2.Range("A:Y").ClearContents
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Excel File to Open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx(*.xlsx),")
Sheet1.Range("B30").Value = FileToOpen
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
Set sheet = wb2.Worksheets(1)
sheet.usedrange.copy destination:=thisworkbook.worksheets(2).range("A1")

End Sub
```

try this code.

Comment: Gave an error of this:  
Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range

Comment: at which line was the error at? can you post the line where the error comes always with your posts.

Comment: Now new error of runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property and method. Error on this line : ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Paste so sorry about that

Comment: It works now!!! Thank you so much !!! have been stuck for two days ! am really grateful for your help !